# Generating results based on gap between dates for a theatre

Tags: mysql, sql, join, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am working on an SQL query, where I have 2 tables named Theatre, Movies like this:

**Theatre**

```
Theatre with columns theatre id and show date:

id      show_date
------------------
1       2018-05-01
2       2018-05-01
1       2018-05-03
3       2018-05-04
2       2018-05-14
3       2018-05-11
2       2018-05-14
```

**Movie**

```
Movie with columns movie id and movie name:

id  name
----------
1   Avatar
2   Spiderman
3   Avengers
```

A theatre shows the same movies regularly until the show date difference for that particular theatre is more than 2 days.

For a theatre, if the show date difference is more than 2 days it changes to the next movie in the list of movies table.

All theatres show movies in the same order.

Now I want to write a query for this scenario.

**The expected output is: (I added comments for each row as an explanation)**

```
theatre_id  show_date   movie
---------------------------------------------

1           2018-05-01  Avatar  /* 1st theatre, 1st date occurrence so picking 1st movie
2           2018-05-01  Avatar  /* 2nd theatre, 1st date occurrence so picking 1st movie */
1           2018-05-03  Avatar  /* 1st theatre, with 1 day gap (1st may 2018 to 3rd may 2018), so picking 1st movie
3           2018-05-04  Avatar  /* 3rd theatre, 1st date occurrence so picking 1st movie */
2           2018-05-10  Spiderman /* 2nd theatre, with 8 days gap (1st may 2018 to 10th may 2018), so picking 2nd movie */
3           2018-05-11  Spiderman /* 3rd theatre, with 6 days gap (4th may 2018 to 11th may 2018) so picking 2nd movie */
2           2018-05-14  Avengers /* 2nd theatre, with 3 days gap (10th may 2018 to 14th may 2018), so picking 3rd movie */
```

**Scripts:**

```
drop table if exists theatre;

CREATE TABLE theatre ( 
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  show_date date NOT NULL
);

drop table if exists movie;

CREATE TABLE movie ( 
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
);


insert into movie values (null, 'Avatar');
insert into movie values (null, 'Spiderman');
insert into movie values (null, 'Avengers');

insert into theatre values( 1, cast('2018-05-01' as date));
insert into theatre values( 2, cast('2018-05-01' as date));
insert into theatre values( 1, cast('2018-05-03' as date));
insert into theatre values( 3, cast('2018-05-04' as date));
insert into theatre values( 2, cast('2018-05-10' as date));
insert into theatre values( 3, cast('2018-05-11' as date));
insert into theatre values( 2, cast('2018-05-14' as date));
```

Comment: Note that, by convention, a column called id is normally assumed to be a surrogate PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit complicated; here is an approach using window functions, available in MySQL 8.0.

As I understand your question, you need to put rows from `theatre` in groups that will later on be assigned the same movie. For this, you can use `lag()` to retrieve the previous `show_date`, and make a window sum that increments everytime a gap of more than 2 days is met. Then, you can bring the `movie` table and assign a movie to each group:

```
select t.id, t.show_date, m.name movie
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        sum(case when show_date <= lag_show_date + interval 2 day then 0 else 1 end) 
            over(partition by id order by show_date) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*, 
            lag(show_date) over(partition by id order by show_date) lag_show_date
        from theatre t
    ) t
) t
inner join (
    select m.*, row_number() over(order by id) grp from movie m
) m
    on m.grp = t.grp
```

Comment: Can you please help me, using this query, I am getting error like this `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 29: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by id order by show_date) grp
    from (
        select 
            ' at line 6`

Comment: @learner: which version of MySQL are you running? `select version()`

Comment: I am using online tool `https://paiza.io/en/languages/mysql`, here version says as `5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4`, Is there a better online tool or mysql which supports this query

Comment: @learner. This query uses window functions, which require MySQL 8.0 (as explained at the beginning of my answer). So it won't run on your version. If I understood your task correctly, it will be way harder to solve if you can't use window functions...